# Adding additional MySQL data folder to server. Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, mysql-5.0

Heres the deal. Removed mysql 5.0.xx and neglected to dump a data folder which is on a mounted drive.

I have mySql 5.6.5 now installed and running and the data folder works fine in the default directory. I attempted to switch the data dir in the my.conf file but that results in the error "The server quit without updating PID file."

What I would like to do is still have my.conf point at the default data directory while also adding the external database to MySQL. This is how I had it set up in mySql 5.0.xx. The only problem is I created the database via a GUI and specified that the data would actually be stored in the mounted drive. I can't quite figure out how to do this via the command line and I have found no good sources of documentation or examples.

Comment: [this link might help you](http://serverfault.com/questions/168957/changing-mysql-data-directory-in-ubuntu-server-10-04)

Comment: the better place for this type of question is [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a symbolic link to the directory on the mounted drive. This is done with the *ln* command:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
ln -s /mounted_drive/data_directory/db_name db_name
```

On Ubuntu the MySQL data folder resides in */var/lib*
Generally you can set this variable in my.cnf http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir in order to change the default data directory.